# Is it possible to enumerate registered eepsite (I2P) subdomains?

Tags: sub-domain, enumeration, i2p

Eepsites are similar to Tor's hidden services, but based on the I2P anonymity network.

Named eepsites use central registrars like `stats.i2p` and `no.i2p`. Each eepsite also has a b32 domain which is a base32-encoded string that is used to connect to the server. The registrars provide a service that maps between named (registered) eepsites and their b32 addresses, much like DNS A and AAAA records provide a mapping between registered web domains and IP addresses.

Is it possible to enumerate eepsite subdomains? For example, if you know of `foo.example.i2p`, is there any way to enumerate subdomains other than `foo` without attempting to connect to each one?